# Variadic function fails in VC2010 and crashes in gcc

Tags: c++, function, variadic

### Question:

I have problems with my variadic function `dbPRINT`. It fails in VS2010 and crashes on GCC 4.8.1

The normal `printf` prints the exe's filename as I wish, but my `dbPRINT` function does not. I guess it has something to do with my variadic function calling a variadic function `fprintf`, or it has something to do with Unicode? Or that the console simply does not understand the strings I'm giving it?

### Code:

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>

#include <irrlicht.h>
using namespace irr;

#define STR(x) #x
#define CAT(x) STR(x)
#define VAR(x) #x " = " CAT(x)

void dbPRINT( const char* formatString, ... )
{
    va_list p;
    va_start(p,formatString);
    fprintf( stdout, formatString, p );
    //fflush( stdout );
    va_end(p);
}

//! Return the full filename of the application executeable.
core::stringc GetExeFilename()
{
//! Windows
#if defined(_IRR_WINDOWS_API_)
    core::stringw tmp;
    wchar_t buf[ MAX_PATH ];
    buf[0] = L'\0';
    if (!GetModuleFileNameW( NULL, (LPWSTR)&buf, MAX_PATH))
    {
        return core::stringc("");
    }
    tmp = buf;  
    tmp.replace(L'\\', L'/');
    return core::stringc( tmp );
//! Posix
#elif defined (_IRR_POSIX_API_)
    c8 buf[1024];
    memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
    if (readlink("/proc/self/exe", buf, sizeof(buf)-1))
    {
        perror("readlink");
        return tmp;
    }
    core::stringc tmp = buf;
    return tmp;
#else
    #warning GetExeFilename() not implemented for this platform.
#endif
    return core::stringc("");
}

//int main()
//int wmain( int argc, wchar_t** argv )
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    // MessageBox( 0, L"Press OK", L"Hi", MB_SETFOREGROUND );
    printf( VAR(WINVER) "\n");
    printf( VAR(_MSC_VER) "\n");
    printf( VAR(WIN32) "\n");
    printf( VAR(WIN64) "\n");

    #if defined(_IRR_WINDOWS_)
        dbPRINT( "#defined _IRR_WINDOWS_\n" );
    #endif

    #if defined(_IRR_WINDOWS_API_)
        dbPRINT( "#defined _IRR_WINDOWS_API_\n" );
    #endif

    #if defined(_IRR_POSIX_API_)
        dbPRINT( "#defined _IRR_POSIX_API_\n" );
    #endif

    #if defined(_IRR_WCHAR_FILESYSTEM)
        dbPRINT( "#defined _IRR_WCHAR_FILESYSTEM\n" );
    #endif

    #if defined(__GNUC__)
        dbPRINT( "#defined __GNUC__\n" );
    #endif

    printf(  "A %s\n", GetExeFilename().c_str() );      // works
    dbPRINT( "B %s\n", GetExeFilename().c_str() );      // fail
    dbPRINT( "C %s, %s\n", "Hallo ", "ANSI" );          // fail
    dbPRINT( "D Hello Information\n" );                 // works
    dbPRINT( "E Hello Error\n" );                       // works
    dbPRINT( "F %ls, %ls\n", L"Hallo ", L"UNICODE" );   // fail
    dbPRINT( "G Hello Information\n" );                 // works
    dbPRINT( "H Hello Error\n" );                       // works

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

### Result:

```
WINVER = 0x0601
_MSC_VER = 1600
WIN32 = 1
WIN64 = WIN64
#defined _IRR_WINDOWS_
#defined _IRR_WINDOWS_API_
A X:/test_variadic_prints.exe        --> OK
B ¦V4                                --> Fail
C ­¼A, ¿ ?                            --> Fail
D Hello Information
E Hello Error
F G Hello Information                --> Fail ( F is empty ? )
H Hello Error
Drücken Sie eine beliebige Taste . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

i think i got it now, this solution seems to work

```
void dbPRINT( const char* formatString, ... )
{
    va_list p;
    va_start(p,formatString);
    const unsigned long int bufferSize = 4096;
    char buffer[bufferSize];
#if defined(_MSC_VER)
    vsnprintf(&(buffer[0]), bufferSize, formatString, p);
#elif defined(__GNUC__)
    vsnprintf(&buffer[0], bufferSize, formatString, p);
#else

#endif
    va_end(p);
    fputs( buffer, stdout );
    fflush( stdout );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void dbPRINT(const char* fmt, ...)
{
    va_list va;
    va_start(va, fmt);
    vprintf(fmt, va);
    fflush(stdout);
    va_end(va);
}
```

If you didn't insist on flushing the output (which I believe happens implicitly when printing a newline anyway) and the void returntype, you could just alias `fprintf()` to `dbPRINT()` using a function pointer.

That said, a few notes:

- Stop using C-style casts.
- Take care that using win32 WCHAR strings doesn't work with this.
- `system("pause")` is obviously nonportable, too.
- Using C++ IOStreams, you could use rdbuf() in order to redirect them flexibly and you would get type safety.
- Using magic numbers (like 4096) doesn't magically make code correct.
- GetModuleFilenameW() could use paths of arbitrary length, your code can't. Call it twice, first to determine the length then to retrieve the data.